# What's the translation of 这是瘤売肉?

Tags: characters, sentence-structure

I'm a Chinese Novel translator and and I'm sort of having problems translating this: 这是瘤売肉。

Comment: what's the 瘤売肉?

Comment: I'm a Chinese, and I haven't see such a word in my life ....

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it's something that the author made up. It doesn't hurt if you use pinyin or any funny sounding word you come up with.